# SpannableGridView change layout issue

Tags: android, recyclerview-layout

I want to use recyclerview layout like this. "0" grid is half a height of screen. "1", "2", "3", "4" are same size and repeatable. When you scroll to down rest of the grids are like small grids. Sorry for my bad mock up.

I discover TwoWayView library but I can't customize it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it :9

I can change LayoutAdapter in Sample app following lines.

```
//final int span1 = (itemId == 0 || itemId == 3 ? 2 : 1);
//final int span2 = (itemId == 0 ? 2 : (itemId == 3 ? 3 : 1));
```

changed to this.

```
final int span2 = (itemId == 0 ? 2 : 1);
final int span1 = (itemId == 0 ? 2 : 1);
```